# Access specific Azure appservice managed by Traffic Manager

Tags: cluster-computing, azure-traffic-manager, azure-appservice

We have an appservice hosting some odata api's in Azure. We are running an instance in Central US and another in East US 2. We have a Traffic Manager profile set up so a single url is balanced between the two instances. There is an intermittent issue, is there a way to hit a specific server as the endpoint to test them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to hit a specific server, you can directly access the instance with each instance domain name. Since Azure Traffic Manager works based on DNS, you can [verify Traffic Manager settings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/traffic-manager/traffic-manager-testing-settings) using the tools like `nslookup` or `dig` to resolve DNS names. To effectively test a performance traffic routing method, you must have **clients located in different parts of the world**.

About the performance, please note that

> The only performance impact that Traffic Manager can have on your
>   website is the **initial DNS lookup**.
>
> **Traffic does NOT flow through Traffic Manager**. Once the DNS lookup
>   completes, the client has an IP address for an instance of your web
>   site. The client connects directly to that address and does not pass
>   through Traffic Manager. The Traffic Manager policy you choose has no
>   influence on the DNS performance. However, a Performance
>   routing-method can negatively impact the application experience. For
>   example, if your policy redirects traffic from North America to an
>   instance hosted in Asia, the network latency for those sessions may be
>   a performance issue.

You may set the DNS TTL value low so that changes propagate quickly (for example, 30 seconds).

In addition, there are [sample tools to measure DNS performance](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/traffic-manager/traffic-manager-performance-considerations#sample-tools-to-measure-dns-performance).

To [troubleshoot a probe failure](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/traffic-manager/traffic-manager-troubleshooting-degraded#troubleshooting), you need a tool that shows the HTTP status code return from the probe URL. There are many tools available that show you the raw HTTP response.

[Fiddler](https://www.telerik.com/fiddler)
[curl](https://curl.haxx.se/)
[wget](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/wget.htm)

Also, you can use the Network tab of the F12 Debugging Tools in Internet Explorer to view the HTTP responses.

Hope this information could help you.